# Button position in a linear layout

Tags: java, android, layout

i'm trying to create button programmatically on a linear layout and i want to have "columns" of buttons but it seems the linear layout automatically put buttons under each other and i can't find a way to make my button position to the top again

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_branch);

    LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
    for(int i =0; i <10; i++) {
        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("Branch1");

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(330,200);
        layoutParams.setMargins(rowNb*330+5, 3, 0, 0); // left, top, right, bottom
        btn.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        linear.addView(btn);
        btnNb++;
        if(btnNb>5)
        {
            rowNb = 1;
        }
    }

}
```

[here's what i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByzAs.png)

Can someone help me out to find a way to make my 2nd columns like the first ? I already tried a btn.SetY or a btn.setGravity

Comment: Why don't you specify orientation LinearLayout layout = /* ... */;
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

Comment: It's already a vertical layout, but i can't find a way to make my button go up on the 2nd column i make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try GridLayout instead of LinearLayout
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html